# нарисовать круг с помощью двумерного массива c# динамический в зависимости от радиуса

Tags: c#

нужно нарисовать круг с помощью двумерного массива C#

Comment: Рисуйте на здоровье, тут никто абсолютно не против этого.

Comment: смешной ответ..

Comment: @БахтиярАширов Каков вопрос, таков ответ.

Comment: раз для вас все так просто так что не ответили?

Comment: "Ну что же вы такие тупые?" - "Ирония судьбы". Есть матрица (двумерный массив). Все элементы, скажем, - нули. В этой матрице назначить некоторым элементам значение, скажем, 1, чтобы они образовали окружность.

Comment: @БахтиярАширов пжл добавьте метку. WinForms,  WPF ?

Comment: ответить на что? Вы вопрос не задали, вы вывалили сюда ваше задание. Мы рады, что вам есть что делать, но никто ваше задание за вас решать не будет

Comment: На основном SO сейчас как раз обсуждают, как нужно ласково и нежно относиться к новым участникам и с любовью менять им подгузники.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен алгоритм [Алгоритм Брезенхэма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Если кратко:

1. На первом шаге надо найти первую точку для рисования. Она может быть, например, слева от центра на расстоянии r (где r - радиус)
2. Вычислить следующую точку с помощью алгоритма Брезенхэма, перейти к ней
3. Когда алгоритм придет к точке из пункта 1 - закончить работу